# React Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

i am trying to use this custom hook thats bring me a local message from a route.

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const useLocalFlashMessages = () => {
    const [LocalFlashMessage, setLocalFlashMessage] = useState();

    const handleMessages = async () => {
        setLocalFlashMessage(await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/localFlashMessages/'))
        return LocalFlashMessage
    };
    return [
        LocalFlashMessage,
        handleMessages
    ]
}

export default useLocalFlashMessages
```

So, when i try to call the "handleMessage" function from this hook in my App.js Component,  this warning appears:   Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of  from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.

There is my App.js:

```
import './css/Header.css';
import Body from './components/Body';
import Footer from './components/App/Footer';
import useLocalFlashMessages from './hooks/useLocalFlashMessages';

function App() {
  const [LocalFlashMessage, handleMessages] = useLocalFlashMessages()
  console.log(LocalFlashMessage)
  
  return (
    <div className="Main">
      <main className="Main-body">
        {LocalFlashMessage ? <div> {LocalFlashMessage}</div> : <div>{handleMessages}</div>}
        <Body />
      </main>
      <footer className="Main-footer">
        <Footer />
      </footer>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

What can i do to solve this?

Comment: Can you confirm that the missing `{` inside the first `div` is just a copy/paste typo? Also can you eliminate other possible causes by trying it without the `Body` and `Footer` being rendered?

Comment: You right, the missing '{' was a copypaste mistake and i'm going to edit it. On the other hand, i tried render without Body and Footer but the warning keep appearing.

Comment: What does your console log output? `console.log(LocalFlashMessage)`?

Comment: It shows a message when i register in another component, like "You have been registered successfully". I just put it for testing.

Comment: you code doesn't show where you actually calling `handleMessages`... and that ternary with `LocalFlashMessage`... is something missing there?

Comment: Oh sorry again, copypaste troubles. I have already edited with the correct 'handleMessages' calling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `await axios` returns an object, which you are trying to render as a component. You cannot do this in React.

I think what you are looking for is to output the message from the axios call which will be in the `data` field

```
const resp = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/localFlashMessages/');
setLocalFlashMessage(resp.data);
return resp.data
```

Theres also a problem on this line:

```
{LocalFlashMessage ? <div> {LocalFlashMessage}</div> : <div>{handleMessages}</div>}
```

`handleMessage` will return a promise which is a function and not a react function. You will need to invoke that within a `useEffect` or other helper function and just render `LocalFlashMessage` instead

Answer (score 0):

**Question solved**. Thanks to these comments, i have restructured my local messages sistem with useEffect() hook.
Now my sistem works with a Component called "ShowLocalMessages" that receives messages data from Local Storage and update its state with it. If a local message exists, it will show it.

Comment: Please mark the above answer as a solution if it solved your problem!